# How is this boundary condition $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} f(x,t) = y_0(x)$ for a PDE called?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If you have a diffusion equation $\partial_t f(x,t) = \partial_x^2 f(x,t) $, where $(x,t) \in [0,a] \times \mathbb{R}$ and then you say $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} f(x,t) = y_0(x)$, how do you call such a boundary condition? My feeling is that this completely determines the solution, is this correct?

If anything is unclear about my question, please let me know.

Comment: "Infinite past" can be a good name.

Comment: alright, seems as if there is no canonical name, so I will pick your suggestion.and is it true that my solution is now completely determined in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that you have to give boundary conditions in $x=0$ and
$x=a$ in order to give a meaning to $\partial _{x}^{2}$. Then its spectrum
becomes discrete
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{x}^{2}=\sum_{n}\lambda _{n}|u_{n}><u_{n}|
\end{equation*}
Usually the $\lambda _{n}$ are non-positive.
Now
\begin{equation*}
f(x,t)=<x|f(t)>=\exp [\partial _{x}^{2}t]f(x,0)=\sum_{n}\exp [\lambda
_{n}t]|u_{n}><u_{n}|f(0)>\overset{t\rightarrow -\infty }{\rightarrow }
y_{0}(x)
\end{equation*}
Then the limit as $t\rightarrow -\infty $ will only exist for those $n$ for
which $\exp [\lambda _{n}t]$ has a limit. Thus all other $<u_{n}|f(0)>$ must
vanish. For positive $\lambda _{n}$  the corresponding terms vanish in the
limit and hence the associated $<u_{n}|f(0)>$ are undetermined. Thus, for $%
y_{0}\neq 0$ only those $n$ for which $\lambda _{n}=0$ contribute.

By the way, your condition is usually refered to as an asymptotic condition
rather than a boundary condition.

Comment: you are right, there are BC's for $\partial_x^2$. But do you know if my solution is unique? Also, I'd be interested to here about a more general equation like $\partial_t f(x,t) = \partial_x^2 + g(x,t) f(x,t)$, where $||g||_{L^2} < \infty$ with respect to t and $C^{\infty}$ for both coordinates. Do you know how this behaves in this more general case?

Comment: The solution must be in the null space of ${∂_x}^2$. As to the more general problem, this is quite complicated since ${∂_x}^2$ and $g(x,t)$ do not commute.

Comment: also in the more general case, where we have an additional $g(x,t)$?

Comment: Then the term with $g(x,t)$ couples the null space to the rest.

Comment: sorry for all my questioning here but what do you mean by: couples the null space to the rest?

Comment: $g(x,t)u_n$ is no longer in the null space even if $u_n$ is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17704/discussion-between-urgje-and-tobias-hurth).

Answer (score 0):

Let be
$$f_1(x,t)=e^t e^x,\qquad f_2(x,t)=0$$
Both are solutions of the equation and in the infinite past:
$$f_1(x,-\infty) = f_2(x,-\infty)=0.$$

Comment: But $f_1$ need not satisfy the boundary conditions in $x=0$ and $x=a$.

Comment: You are righth, but the only stated boundary condition is at the infinite past.

Comment: No, see the author's reaction to my earlier answer. Without these boundary conditions the problem is ill-defined.

Comment: Solution: change $e^x$ for $c_1 e^x+c_2 e^{-x}$ (solution of $y''=y$ + boundary conditions).

Comment: So ${y_0}=0$? It seems to me  that the proper solution is a time-independent function for which  ${{∂_{x}}^2}f$ vanishes.

Comment: The expression asymptotic condition for large time limits is common practise in scattering theory.